# Limited Results in the Windows 10 Search "Best Match" Feature

Tags: windows-10, search

I was wondering if there's a way to tweak and configure what will be shown under "Best Match" when using Windows 10 Search (the one in the taskbar, not File Explorer).

In 99% of the searches I perform, nothing shows up under "Best Match" and I have to make a few more clicks and search again through that lower left "My stuff" button.

The remaining 1% appears elegantly under "Best Match". That 1% seem to include, other than applications, very specific, system-defined locations, like desktop and the user's folder (but sadly, none of my files are stored in either location) - and that is what I would like change: to have my own files and directories appear under "Best match".

Just to be clear, if I go to "My stuff" I always find what I want, so indexing is basically fine. It's just that I don't want to go to "My stuff" each time, it's tedious.

Thanks.